# Second Marker not placed in a google map

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a google map here that is supposed to place 2 markers.  One for tree location and one for trailhead location.

The tree location is not set, although the lat/lng is recognized.  Any idea what may be causing this problem?

The url with the source is here:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/widget.php?type=hike&hike_id=108&width=500&height=500

Thank you!
- Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see both markers in the map.

The problem with Google Maps is that it sometimes caches the markers strangely. What I sometimes do is just change the name of the file with markers when I want it fresh.

Comment: You are right.  In a different browser I do see 2 markers.  The problem is that my JS is in the same file as the php script so I can not change the file name.  Is there another way to handle this?

Comment: @Genadinik, I'm not sure what options you have for that scenario, I've always been supplying data to GM through a KML file.

Answer (score 1):

When you reference your javascript file, which I'm assuming from the comments of Cz's answer is created by PHP, add a timestamp to the end of the filename.

If the page is already using PHP:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="myjavascript.php?<?php echo date('Ymdhi'); ?>"></script>`

Example using javascript only:

```
var script = document.createElement('script'); script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'myjavascript.php?' + new Date().getTime();
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
```